# Multiple Console Input in C

Tags: c

Can Someone please help me how to approach this problem?

[image: The Problem]

We don't know the number of inputs the user may give and that's the main problem!

Comment: Please include details of the question as text, not an image.  Images are only to be used to provide user interface aspects of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the return value of the `scanf` function: it returns the number of values that have been read and it will return `-1` when no input are available.

Here's a good starting point:

```
int x;
while(scanf("%d", &x) == 1) {
    // Code your solution here.
}
```

Comment: To the OP: Here, the return value must be checked. If it is 1, `scanf` scanned an `int` successfully. If it is 0, `scanf` failed to scan an `int` (Due to invalid input such as an alphabet. If it is -1 (`EOF`), the input has been ended.

Comment: Sorry, but IMO it is also a shame to ask questions before doing some research. This is not the ideal kind of question here.

Answer (score -1):

The return value of `scanf()` won't be enough here. For example, "3 5 a b 7" expects "Invalid Input", rather than "8".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num, sum = 0;
    while(scanf(" %d", &num) == 1)
        sum += num;
    if (getchar() == EOF)
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    else
        puts("Invalid Input");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int sum=0,a,d;
    char f;
    while(d=scanf("%d%c",&a,&f))
    {
        sum=a+sum;
        if(f=='\n')
            break;
    }
    if(d==2)
         printf("%d\n",sum);
    else
         printf("Invalid Input\n");
    return 0;
}
```